# Type mismatch while trying to create a root node in VBA

Tags: vba, vb6, treeview, nodes

I need to create a root node on a treeView, but when i try to do so i get a error: Type mismatch.
I'm using this function to add a new node:

```
Set nodx = Me.TreeView1.Nodes.Add(, , key, Item)
```

I tried to pass a value to the first two parameters but it didn't work:

```
Set nodx = Me.TreeView1.Nodes.Add(Nothing, tvwChild, key, Item)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is your 'key' variable (should be a string, as should 'Item') and have you declared 'nodex' as Node? -That works fine in Vb6, so I assume it's the same in Vba.

Comment: The variable key is a string, i.e. "P10072023113611",  and nodx is declared as node. In the early versions of the system i'm working on that code works, but i updated the dll files and now it wont accept that way

Comment: No idea in that case I'm afraid. It's a very long time since I used Vb6/vba.

Comment: Set nodx = Me.TreeView1.Nodes.Add(  , tvwChild, key, Item)  Don't use Nothing...

Comment: The only thought I have since you say you've updated the dll files is that you may need to change from version 5 to version 6 of the Microsoft Treeview Control on the Vba Additional Controls dialog.

Comment: Place your cursor just before 'key', press ctrl-shift-i, and take a look at what parameters are being expected.

Comment: The only way I can reproduce this is if ```Item``` is Nothing or cannot be autocast into a string.